# Joomla 2.5 component controller loading

Tags: joomla, components

I've been trying to learn how to build a Joomla component.

I've been using http://joomlaprogrammingbook.com/ book which is great.  I can now do plugins and modules without too much of a problem.  However I'm getting stuck with how certain controllers get loaded for components.  The site given has the full code if it's needed.

The initial controller loaded is:

```
 class JoomproSubsController extends JController
{
    /**
    * @var      string  The default view.
    * @since    1.6
    */
protected $default_view = 'submanager';

/**
 * Method to display a view.
 *
 * @param   boolean         $cachable   If true, the view output will be cached
 * @param   array           $urlparams  An array of safe url parameters and their variable types, for valid values see {@link JFilterInput::clean()}.
 *
 * @return  JController     This object to support chaining.
 */ 
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
{
    JLoader::register('JoomproSubsHelper', JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/joomprosubs.php');

    // Load the submenu.
    JoomproSubsHelper::addSubmenu(JRequest::getCmd('view', 'submanager'));

    $view = JRequest::getCmd('view', 'submanager');
    $layout = JRequest::getCmd('layout', 'default');
    $id = JRequest::getInt('id');

    // Check for edit form.
    if ($view == 'subscription' && $layout == 'edit' && !$this->checkEditId('com_joomprosubs.edit.subscription', $id)) {
        // Somehow the person just went to the form - we don't allow that.
        $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_UNHELD_ID', $id));
        $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');
        $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_joomprosubs&view=submanager', false));

        return false;
    }

    parent::display();

    return $this;
}
```

}

I can see how and when this is loaded.  However at some point in this it also seems to load `class JoomproSubsControllerSubManager extends JControllerAdmin`

now I though that to do this it would need a url which included `com_joomproSubs?task=submanager`

but that doesn't exist.  So my question is how can this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Joomla! everything passes through `index.php` (although in the front-end you won't see `index.php` in the URL if the SEF options are turned on).

#### Without SEF etc

So the entry points are `index.php` or `/administrator/index.php` (for the backend). To this are appended some parameters that tell Joomla! how to route the request.

1. `option=X`
2. `task=Y.Z`
3. `view=V`

#### `option`

This is the parameter that tells Joomla what component is to handle the request. e.g. `option=com_content` for the component that handles standard articles. Subsequent to the component value being determined, Joomla is then expecting everything to be in the matching directory. In our example this will be `/components/com_content/` or for the backend `/administrator/components/com_content/`

#### `task`

The `task` parameter can take a dot notation value of the form `controller.method` e.g. `task=article.edit` in the Article Manager. Using the elements of this value Joomla! loads the `article.php` file in the `/com_content/controllers/` directory and fires the method `edit`

#### `view`

The `view` parameter is used to nominate a specific view within the same controller e.g. again in the `com_content` component you see these two variations in the value of view:

`/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured`

`/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=articles`

Answer (score 1):

Subcontrollers are used for tasks like new, edit, delete, save and so on for components items as there might be different types of these (banners/ clients/ tracks) having different functionality (item, list, form).

Using an URLs
 `com_joomprosubs?task=item.display` you execute controller method `JoomprosubsControlerItem->display()` in file components/com_joomprosubs/controllers/item.php.

If you'd use 
`com_joomprosubs?task=submanager` you'd would `JoomprosubsController->submanager()` in components/com_joomprosubs/controller.php.