# Which component's controller handle the form request of NEW item?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

After checking this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143293/joomla-2-5-component-controller-loading/16158772#16158772), I know that Joomla use `task=X.Y` to call the controller to handle the request.

But if I click NEW button on com_categories component, it will access the URL of `/administrator/index.php?option=com_categories&view=items` and containing the POST data as below:
[image]

Then the URL get redirected to `/administrator/index.php?option=com_categories&view=item&layout=edit`.

My question is why the URL `/administrator/index.php?option=com_categories&view=items` don't have the `task=X.Y` and it can redirect to `/administrator/index.php?option=com_categories&view=item&layout=edit`?

I know that it contains the POST data with `task=item.add`, but which controller convert this POST data to the destination URL and get redirected to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually (on 2.5.14), when you click on the "New" button in the Category Manger view, the first request generates a POST:

```
POST /administrator/index.php?option=com_categories&view=categories HTTP/1.1
```

`POST` requests usually send query strings in the `HTTP` message body not just in the URL, in this case the `POST` request has the following *form* data in the body:

```
filter_search   
filter_level    
filter_published    
filter_access   
filter_language 
limit   5
limitstart  0
order[] 1
order[] 1
order[] 1
order[] 1
order[] 2
batch[assetgroup_id]    
batch[language_id]  
batch[category_id]  
batch[move_copy]    m
extension   com_content
task    category.add
boxchecked  0
filter_order    a.lft
filter_order_Dir    asc
original_order_values   1,1,1,1,2
796194955f38a0d8db484c92d92ca5ce    1
```

You will notice this has a `task` parameter that has the value `category.add` (*not item.add*), this is taken into account by the `JController` class when `getInstance($prefix, $config)` is called in the `com_categories` entry point file:

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Categories');
```

The `JController` class converts `category.add` into a `$type` of `category` and a `$task` of `add`. The `$type` value is used to assemble the path to the controller in conjunction with the components base path ( in this case `/pathto/site/administrator/components/com_categories` ).

So, when the instantiated `JController` class receives the `->execute($task)` message in `com_categories/categories.php` entry point file:

`$controller->execute(JRequest::getVar('task'));`

it's actually already a controller of type `CategoriesControllerCategory` which is the what you would expect to handle the `New` button request.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, refer to your explain "xxxthis is taken into account by the JController class when getInstance($prefix, $config)xxx", so the JController class convert POST data to $type and $task variable?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the `JController` version of `getInstance()` in `/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php` you can see the conversion steps.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing: I found `getWord()` with defination "Fetches and returns a given filtered variable" and `getVar()` with defination "Fetches and returns a given variable." What is the meaning of filtered variable and given variable? Could you provide some exmaple? Thanks again.

Comment: It's probably best you ask this in another question, the answer might help others.