# How Joomla implement the item publishing and item unpublishing function?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Refer to my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554295/which-components-controller-handle-the-form-request-of-new-item), I have figured out that Joomla call the controller with the POST data `task=X.Y`, however I found that if I publish an item (`task items.publish`) or unpublish an item (`task items.unpublish`), they also calling the controller `JControllerAdmin` of the function `publish` but not the function of `publish` and `unpublish`.

I know that Joomla may convert the POST data `task items.unpublish` to call the `publish` function instead of `unpublish`, but anyone know where is the code of converting this POST data?

p.s.: I have added the code `exit();` at the beginning of the function `publish` under controller `JControllerAdmin` and testing for publish or unpublish an item, the result is same --> blank page. So I wondering how Joomla implement these function.

Comment: Its better to avoid editing core file you can write same function on your controller it will override joomla's default methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla's Default function for publish and unpublished are written in this file

```
libraries\joomla\application\component\controlleradmin.php
```

But its better to avoid editing on that and override those function if you require customization on it in your controller file.

Hope its helps..

Comment: I can't find `unpublish` function on `JControllerAdmin` http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Application/JControllerAdmin.html, either his parent class `JController ` http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Application/JController.html

Comment: published is 0 that means its unpublished check the construct() in the file for register task section.

Comment: Thanks for providing this hints.